# Inner join with comma separated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2012

I have a master table RejectionList and one Transaction table where rejection reason is multiple.

Say MSTR_Rejection is the master table name and RejectionID, RejectionReason are two fields.

```
RejectionID      RejectionReason 

1                Invalid Mobile
2                Invalid Email
3                Invalid Pincode
```

Now I have a Trasaction table where rejectionID is multiple time

```
 TrasactionID      RejectionReason 

    1                1
    2                2,3
    3                1,2,3
```

Now I want to make a Rejection Report Group By RejectionReason from Transaction table. And I stuck here. Please help me out.

Comment: comma-separated columns always indicate a broken database-design...

Comment: It will be good if you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using MS Sqlserver 2012

Comment: @piet.t "always" is a extreme word to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a very bad database design.  Instead of a comma-separated list, you should use a junction table.

That said, you can do what you want with `like`.  Here is an example:

```
select r.rejectionreason, count(*)
from MSTR_Rejection r join
     Transaction t
     on ',' + t.rejectionreason + ',' like '%,' + cast(m.RejectionId as varchar(255)) + ',%'
group by r.rejectionreason;
```

The above is not particularly efficient.  If you want performance, you need to fix the database structure to use a junction table.

Comment: Dear Gordon Linoff, what is m.rejectionid

Comment: Dear Gordon Linoff, i Fixed the isseu and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you may wanna try LISTAGG instead for oracle, for sql server, haven't use on if they have an equivalent of it:

LISTAGG:
select 
    claim_no, 
    sum(amt) pay_amt, 
    listagg(payee, '/ ') within group (order by payee desc) payname 
from 
    SCHEMA.TABLENAME
group by claim_no

```
Here's my table
CLAIM_NO                PAYEE          AMT
2014-1-10-1315 H-088    john           100
2014-1-10-1315 H-091    john           100
2014-1-10-1315 H-087    john           1000
2014-1-10-1315 H-113    op personnel    1150
2014-1-10-1315 H-087    tim            575.25

here's the result:
CLAIM_NO                PAY_AMT     PAYNAME
2014-1-10-1315 H-087    1575.25     tim/ john
2014-1-10-1315 H-088    100         john
2014-1-10-1315 H-091    100         john
2014-1-10-1315 H-113    1150        op personnel
```

The group_concat and stuff i said earlier, haven't use that actually, i just google it.
you can replace the forward slash separator by a comma.

Comment: Please tell me how. I need that thing.